# Custom Javascript Variable in GTM to convert date (string) to date

Tags: javascript, date, google-tag-manager

I am pulling a date of birth as a string from a form on a website im looking after. I need to be able to derive an age from that date string. 
My thoughts are converting it into a proper date using a split (its delimited by "%2F") and calculating from that but my syntax isnt that good so im having real trouble. 
The code im working with to pull the string I need is;

```
function() {
var inputField = document.getElementById("date-of-birth-input");
return inputField.value || "";
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Start with [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results), then to calculate age perhaps [*JavaScript calculate years and days from start date*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570232/javascript-calculate-years-and-days-from-start-date).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the user input the date in a format like `1/1/1990`, you could do something like this:

```
var inputField = document.getElementById("date-of-birth-input"); // `1/1/1990`
var today = new Date().getFullYear();
var birthdate = new Date(inputField).getFullYear();
var age = today - birthdate;
```

The JavaScript `Date` constructor is pretty flexible in what it can turn into a date, so you might not need to go through splitting-string hassles. Check out the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: This relies on unreliable parsing of the Date constructor to create a date. Also, the age calculation will likely be incorrect given that a person's age is not simply the difference in the year value (e.g. someone born on 31 Dec 2016 is not 1 year old on 1 Jan 2017).

Comment: @RobG As far as the Date constructor parsing unreliably, my example will always parse reliably since I used the format `1/1/1990`. I also pointed to the docs so the OP could discover other ways to play with the constructor.

Comment: Please see MDN [*Date.parse*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) and [*Date*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I did something similar to this. Except I split the date string into an array and created a calculation for the no of months and days as a % of the year (just averaged 30.14 days per month) to get the number of years plus .xxxxx. Then adjust with another -0.05 to adjust for leap year etc. Its accurate down to within a day which for what I need to record is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Date format varies in different countries. In US the date format is `MM-DD-YYYY` while in Asian countries the date format is `DD-MM-YYYY` and in China its `'YYYY-MM-DD`'. The right way to go about dealing with dates is using [**Moment.js**](https://momentjs.com/)

If you have a simple application/website include moment in your `<head>` tag as follows

```
<script src="moment.js"></script>
```

(Hoping you have downloaded moment.js and kept in the same structure as index.html). Otherwise use this if you want to use it directly from the net without downloading.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/locale/af.js"></script>
```

Then use the following

```
   function() {
    /* First-make sure you format moment according to your giving locale.
      I'm formating here according to the US date format */
    var inputField = moment(document.getElementById("date-of-birth-input")).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
    return moment().diff(inputField, 'years');
    }
```

I hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: The OP has not noted moment.js as a tag or in the question, so your answer should not rely on it. When parsing a date string, you should always tell the parser the format, otherwise you might as well use *Date.parse* (which is not recommended). There is nothing in this answer that the OP could not have learnt from the moment.js documentation, so it should just be a comment.